# I understand how to connect web mysql database with C# windows form application

Tags: c#, mysql, database

Last day, I spent much time searching tutorials for connecting `Mysql WEB database` with `C# windows form application`, I tried many codes and watch about 10 similar tutorials but nothing help, I mean it not help me, because its not connecting type what I need...

I want to connect this database:
[Databsae image by lightshot](https://prnt.sc/s3zfou)

In this code:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CS_Enginer
{
    public partial class login : Form
    {
        public login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == "Username")
            {
                textBox1.Text = "";
                textBox1.ForeColor = Color.DimGray;
            }

        }

        private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == "")
            {
                textBox1.Text = "Username";
                textBox1.ForeColor = Color.DimGray;
            }
        }

        private void textBox2_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox2.Text == "Password")
            {
                textBox2.Text = "";
                textBox2.ForeColor = Color.DimGray;
                textBox2.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
            }

        }

        private void textBox2_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox2.Text == "")
            {
                textBox2.Text = "Password";
                textBox2.ForeColor = Color.DimGray;
                textBox2.UseSystemPasswordChar = false;
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        }

        private void login_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void login_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I know that I should not post images but i don't know how to explain it... Sorry about that and thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I creating login sytem in c# windows form application, and i want to connect on web database for what i send image..

Comment: Look ill send you images now, just a moment :)

https://prnt.sc/s3zosr

https://prnt.sc/s3zp5r

Comment: I said i watch many tutorials but i don't understand and everything what i tried not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note**: The following will work only if the remote connection to the database is enabled from the website's CPANEL.

For connecting to a database you would need a connection string and libraries that will help you connect and retrieve data from the database. For MySql you can use the MySql connecter that is provided here - [MySql connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)

Once downloaded add a reference of the connector to your project by right-clicking on your project name and selecting 'Add' and then 'Reference'.

After adding the reference, import the classes in your project `using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;`.

Now, you need to form the connection string and open a connection as follows -

```
private void MySqlInteraction()
    {
        string connString = null;
        MySqlConnection mySqlConn;
        // It would be better if the below connection string is provided by the vendor
        // of the database website that you are trying to access as you might not have
        // all the required information
        connString = "server=youronlineserver;database=dbname;uid=root;pwd=abc123;";
        mySqlConn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
        try
        {
            mySqlConn.Open();
            MessageBox.Show ("Connection Open ! ");
            //enter your db querying logic here
            mySqlConn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you ensure that remote connection is allowed to the db?

Comment: ill go check it, just a moment

Comment: Its not possible to enable remote connection on this web because it is shared web..

Comment: In that case, I don't think so you will be able to access the remote server. One thing that you can still try is if there is some sort of IP whitelisting on the server in which you can give access to particularly your IP. Let me know if anything else is needed on this. Also if the answer helped you please mark it as accepted.